# RemovedIn20Warning when inserting a record using engine.connect()

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am new to SQLAlchemy. I am trying to execute a simple insert statement, but I get a "removed In 2.0" warning.

```
from sqlalchemy import (MetaData, Table, Column, Integer, Numeric, String,
                        ForeignKey, create_engine)

metadata = MetaData()

cookies = Table('cookies', metadata,
                Column('cookie_id', Integer(), primary_key=True),
                Column('cookie_name', String(50), index=True),
                Column('cookie_recipe_url', String(255)),
                Column('cookie_sku', String(55)),
                Column('quantity', Integer()),
                Column('unit_cost', Numeric(12, 2))
                )

ins = cookies.insert().values(
    cookie_name="chocolate chip",
    cookie_recipe_url="http://some.aweso.me/cookie/recipe.html",
    cookie_sku="CC01",
    quantity="12",
    unit_cost="0.50"
)

engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/cookies')
with engine.connect() as conn:
    result = conn.execute(ins)
```

Here is the warning:

```
RemovedIn20Warning: Deprecated API features detected! These feature(s) are not compatible with SQLAlchemy 2.0. To prevent incompatible upgrades prior to updating applications, ensure requirements files are pinned to "sqlalchemy<2.0". Set environment variable SQLALCHEMY_WARN_20=1 to show all deprecation warnings.  Set environment variable SQLALCHEMY_SILENCE_UBER_WARNING=1 to silence this message. (Background on SQLAlchemy 2.0 at: https://sqlalche.me/e/b8d9)
  result = conn.execute(ins)
```

I tried to find how to execute the statements in the docs, but it seems they are using the same connection object and execute method. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe all the docs haven't been updated yet.

The problem is that your code is dependent on autocommit which is being removed.  The link below the examples has some more details.

ADDED: You can also set `future=True` when using `create_engine` and then your connections will have the ability to `commit` and the warning won't be raised.  Note by using the new 2.0 functionality, `future=True`, that your inserts will not be committed unless you call `conn.commit()`.

```py
engine = create_engine(..., future=True)

with engine.connect() as conn:
    conn.execute(ins)
    conn.commit()
```

OR Try using one of these:

```py
with engine.connect() as conn, conn.begin():
    conn.execute(ins)

with engine.connect() as conn:
    with conn.begin():
        conn.execute(ins)

with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(ins)
```

[migration-core-connection-transaction](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/migration_20.html#migration-core-connection-transaction)

Comment: Thanks for this valuable document as I probably need to think twice about other documentation. I think they need to put a big warning there.

Comment: @MohammedElbagoury My answer wasn't really complete and I think this is a complex situation related to migrating from 1.4 to 2.0.  The doc examples actually work but in 2.0.  If you are using 1.4 you can set the `future=True` flag on create_engine and then the warning is not raised but nothing is commited unless you call `conn.commit()`.

Comment: Actually, the guide provides an example for 1.4 and another one for 2.0. The snippet you provided is the one for 1.4 and it worked just fine. I tried using the ```connection.commit()``` method but it doesn't exist in the 1.4 version so, it only works for the 2.0 version. Reading the details in the guide, this is all about commits to be implicit in versions prior to 2.0 and explicit in the 2.0 version.